# Risk in reducing NTFS log size

Tags: windows, ntfs

I recently tried to update from Windows 7 to 10, and was unable to as there was insufficient space on the system partition.

One of the solutions recommended was truncating the [NTFS log size to 5MB](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3a6znd/we_couldnt_update_the_system_reserved_partition/). I did this with chkdsk:

```
chkdsk Y: /F /X /L:5000
```

This immediately freed up 50MB of my 100MB partition. Why was the log taking up so much of the partition - and do I face any problems by reducing the log size? I presume the operation restricts the log size permanently?

Comment: Its just a log, you limit it to 1MB if you want, it would just continue to replace that 1MB.

Comment: @Ramhound - Are there any disadvantages to having a significantly shorter log? Why isn't it a more sensible size by default? Or would it just grow to take up all the space available..

Comment: The log is only generated for humans.  Windows could careless what size log you allow it to generate.

Comment: @Ramhound: "The log is only generated for humans." - think that roughly answers my question, thanks! Not sure why it's permitted to grow to be 50% of the partition - but if it doesn't matter, that's great. Would you mind posting that in an answer?

Comment: It took 50% of the partition because it was configured to take up that much space.  In 99.9% of the cases that isn't a problem.  The real answer is that partition is suppose to be 350 MB normally, which is the reason, normally it isn't a problem.

Comment: @Ramhound. Right, thanks. Was wondering whether it was worth resizing the partition, as it involves moving the other one first, but sounds like I should make the effort. Cheers!

Comment: The logfile is not "only generated for humans." In this case, it's not a log of events, it is a transaction log much like an SQL database might have. Completely removing the log can cause corruption of the filesystem. Using the CHKDSK option to reduce the size of the log file is a safe way of shrinking it.